# Can i expect a property to retain its assigned class?

Tags: c#

Maybe a bit of a philosophical, but should I generally, in C#, expect a property with an interface type to retain its assigned class?

For example a class property like this:

```
public IBehavior Behavior { get; set; }
```

that gets assigned a implmented class

```
instance.Behavior = new ImplementedBehavior();
```

should i generally expect this cast to succeed?

```
Assert.IsNotNull(instance.Behavior as ImplementedBehavior);
```

Or is it lost, and i should have kept a reference to the instantiated `ImplementedBehavior` instead?

```
var ib = new ImplementedBehavior();
instance.Behavior = ib;
Assert.IsNotNull(ib as ImplementedBehavior);
```

Clarification:
Looking to use an external class, that when assigned a class similar to what is done above, changes the content of `instance.Behavior` internally after i set it, to return an instance of `SomeOtherBehavior`
Can I assume this is bad behavior and not in the spirit of C#?

GitHub issue related to the question:
https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/19013

Comment: "should i generally expect this cast to succeed?" - if you're the only one who assigns that thing, you can trust it. But why have an interface then? Why do you prefer to have the class instead of the interface? How will it differ?

Comment: @ThomasWeller added a clarification part

Comment: The premise is wrong. "For example a class property like this: `public IBehavior Behavior { get; set; }`" - that's *not* the case in the linked Github example.

Comment: When you set the property to a class that implements `IBehavior`, the property is set to the actual class object (the reference to it in memory), and no implicit conversion is done behind the scenes. The property type is just a "promise" that the property is set to an object that is implementing that type, and nothing more.

Comment: @ErikKarlsson Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] of the problem you have. It is unclear what the actual problem is you have.

Comment: @ErikKarlsson I think your edit made the question completely opinion-based - it is valid to return different value from getter than one that was used in setter (which can be done for many reasons like range-limited values can clamp incoming value to the range) and that choice is 100% left to class author to decide. Whether such author makes "good" choice is not an area SO can come up with factual answer (it is definitely not objectively "bad" choice like building SQL queries with string concatenation of user input).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I expect a property to retain its assigned class?

No.

It may not even be accepted in the first place, e.g.

```cs
public IBehavior Behavior { 
   get {...}
   set { if (!value.HasCapabilityX) return; ... }; 
}
```

It may simply be changed by some other code that has access to the same object (`instance`):

```cs
Thread A:
   instance.Behavior = new ImplementationA();
Thread B:
   instance.Behavior = new ImplementationB();
```

There are object oriented design patterns that promote the idea of changing the object, e.g. the [decorator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) and [proxy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern), e.g.

```cs
public IBehavior Behavior { 
   get {...}
   set { _behavior = new PermissionsDecorator(new LoggingDecorator(value)); }; 
}
```

> Should I generally expect this cast to succeed?

No.

> Or is it lost [...] ?

Maybe.

> and I should have kept a reference to the instantiated ImplementedBehavior instead?

If you need something that `ImplementedBehavior` can do which `IBehavior` can't do, then yes, keep a reference.

> Can I assume this is bad behavior and not in the spirit of C#?

This is not bad behavior. It is good practice to only expect the interface to fulfill the contract that was specified by the interface.

Answer (score 1):

The property can be assigned any value that implements `IBehavior`:

```
public class BehaviorA : IBehavior { }
public class BehaviorB : IBehavior { }
...
instance.Behavior = new BehaviorA();
instance.Behavior = new BehaviorB();
```

So in general, you CANNOT expect a property's value to be of a particular type that derives from the property's declared type.

Comment: I added a clarification part, how common is it that a class do such a change internally after assignment?

Comment: @ErikKarlsson That's impossible to say, unless you can view the source code and verify whether or not such a reassignment actually happens.

Answer (score 0):

this

```
Assert.IsNotNull(instance.Behavior as ImplementedBehavior);
```

will work so long as *you* dont change `instance.Behavior`, it wont happen spontaneously. But if you also have

```
class Imp2 : IBehavior{
}
```

and then do

```
instance.Behavior = new Imp2();
```

then that assert will fail.

Comment: Added a clarification part, it's an external class, that changes it after i assigned it, therefor "spontaneously"

Comment: Note that in the linked Github issue, it is a 3rd party implementation of the property. It is not guaranteed to be implemented as `public IBehavior Behavior { get; set; }` but rather as `public IBehavior Behavior { get; set { _behavior = new Decorator(value);} }`

Comment: @ErikKarlsson still no, since you cannot recompile the class in the middle of program execution

Comment: @ErikKarlsson I feel there is something more complicated going on here. YOu need to tell us what the problem is , not what you think might be going on

Comment: "will work so long as you dont change instance.Behavior" - if someoneelse has a reference to `instance`, someone else can change the value, too.

Answer (score 0):

Let me give you a simple example using

```
public interface IType
{
    string Text { get; set; }
    int Number { get; set; }
}

public class MyClass
{
    public IType MyProperty { get; set; }
}

public class MyFirstType : IType
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public char Letter { get; set; }
}

public class MySecondType : IType
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

And here is the usage with comments that explain what's going on:

```
var instance = new MyClass(); // creates a new object of type "MyClass" in memory
var myFirstType = new MyFirstType(); // creates a new object of type "MyFirstType" in memory
var mySecondType = new MySecondType(); // creates a new object of type "MySecondType" in memory

// setting property
instance.MyProperty = myFirstType; // MyProperty is now simply referencing "myFirstType" using the address to its position in memory
instance.MyProperty = mySecondType; // The memory address to "myFirstType" is now replaced by the memory address to "mySecondType"

// printing values of MyProperty
Console.WriteLine(instance.MyProperty.Text); // will work.
Console.WriteLine(instance.MyProperty.Number); // will work.
Console.WriteLine(instance.MyProperty.Letter); // compiler error. IType does not specify this "Letter" property.
Console.WriteLine(instance.MyProperty.Price); // compiler error. IType does not specify this "Price" property. However, it is in memory on the object, but the compiler will not infer the type of the property unless the property is explicitly casted.

// casting
var convertedPropertyA = (MyFirstType)instance.MyProperty; // throws an exception since the property is currently set to an object of type "MySecondType".
var convertedPropertyB = (MySecondType)instance.MyProperty; // works because the property is set to an object of type "MySecondType".

// modifying the values of the property
instance.MyProperty.Text = "new text"; // this works
instance.MyProperty.Number = 123; // this works
((MySecondType)instance.MyProperty).Price = 14.99; // this works

Console.WriteLine(instance.MyProperty.Text); // prints "new text"
Console.WriteLine(instance.MyProperty.Number); // prints "123"
Console.WriteLine(((MySecondType)instance.MyProperty).Price); // prints "14.99"
```